# Refractor if statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, object-literal

I want to refractor a piece of code

```
if (res1 && res1.e > maxEnergy) {
    maxRes = res1;
    maxEnergy = res1.e;
}
if (res2 && res2.e > maxEnergy) {
    maxRes = res2;
    maxEnergy = res2.e;
}
if (res3 && res3.e > maxEnergy) {
    maxRes = res3;
    maxEnergy = res3.e;
}
```

Is there any best way to do this piece of code in a shorter segment?
With the use of Object literal or switch statement?

Comment: `res1 && res1.e > maxEnergy` => `res1?.e > maxEnergy`

Comment: Actually i want all the three if's to be consolidated into a shorted version not just their condition

Comment: Something like `Math.max(...[res1?.e || 0, res2?.e || 0, res3?.e || 0, maxEnergy])` maybe

Comment: Just leave it like this. Atleast the one who maintains is later does not have to twist his brain to understand what is *supposed* to happen. I prefer to maintain clean / commented / understandable code over minified shorthanded one liners any day.

Comment: I prefer loops and arrays if possible: `[res1, res2, res3].forEach(res => {if (res?.e > maxEnergy) { maxRes = res; maxEnergy = res.e; });`

Comment: @ChrisG
This extract is not working it gives null

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/zf3mjca4/ (with array as in the comment or without)

Answer (score 3):

Much shorter and still readable (IMHO even more readable):

```
[res1, res2, res3].forEach(res => {
  if (res?.e > maxEnergy) {
    maxRes = res;
    maxEnergy = res.e;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why use forEach over a for-of loop ?

Comment: @Sadiinso IMHO it's more readable to see first the list of items I iterate over. In a for-of loop the list of items is near the end of the first line. Not so readable. It's easier to format a long array at the beginning of the line than in the loop header.

Comment: The iterated items are indeed in first, but this introduce some noise in the form of a lambda expression. But as you said, this is more about personal preference.

Comment: @Sadiinso This _"noise in the form of a lambda expression"_ is very typical for JavaScript. I would even consider a `forEach` loop more JavaScript-ic than a `for-of` loop. It fits better into the environment of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: Whether it fits or not depends on your programming style (functional vs imperative, both are available in JS).

Comment: @Sadiinso Using a `for-of` loop instead of `forEach` is an opinion but using a `for-of` instead of `filter`, `map`, `sort`, `flatMap`, ... is just bad code style. It's not the question about functional vs. imperative programming styles.

Comment: Programming style is very subjective; though this is deviating from the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just another take on the problem. When I see some operation being repeated (the if statement), I like to move that code to a function so I can use it later in some other context.

```
let currentMax= {
    e: 0
}

const res1 = {
    e: 90
};
const res2 = {
    e: 170
};
const res3 = {
    e: 10
};

function findMaxEnergy(res, currentMaxRes) {
  if (res && res.e > currentMaxRes.e) {
    return res;
  }
  return currentMaxRes;
}

// now you can use it one by one
// currentMax = findMaxEnergy(res1, currentMax);
// currentMax = findMaxEnergy(res2, currentMax);
// currentMax = findMaxEnergy(res3, currentMax);

// or with an array and a loop
[res1, res2, res3].forEach(res => {
  currentMax = findMaxEnergy(res, currentMax);
});

console.log(currentMax);
```